# DocumentRoot and htaccess files

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, httpd, documentroot

I have a muluitple vhosts set up all with the same DocumentRoot pointing to a common set of files, I have set up AliasMatch for for the bespoke files on each site, I was wondering if I can have a .htaccess file for each vhost.

```
#Sample vhost
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
    ServerName mytest.com
    ServerAlias www.mytest.com
    DocumentRoot /home/commonfiles/public_html
    ......
    AliasMatch /css/(.*) /home/ftpuser/public_html/mycss/$1
</VirtualHost>

#Sample vhost 2
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
    ServerName mytest2.com
    ServerAlias www.mytest2.com
    DocumentRoot /home/commonfiles/public_html
    ......
    AliasMatch /css/(.*) /home/ftpuser2/public_html/mycss/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

I have added in an AliasMatch for the .htaccess but that didn't work.

```
#vhost 1
AliasMatch /.htaccess /home/ftpuser/public_html/.htaccess
#vhost 2
AliasMatch /.htaccess /home/ftpuser2/public_html/.htaccess
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I take it that you're not aware that aliases only apply to requested files, not Apache-internal files?

Comment: I am now, this is all kinda new to me. Trying to learn as I go.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that's going to work, the override stuff is probably happening beforehand. I'm not 100% here without wading through documentation.

What I'd do though is look at the [AccessFileName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#accessfilename) directive which can be specified per VirtualHost.

Specify a different AccessFileName in the two VirtualHosts and you should be good to go. Bear in mind, this will change the filename Apache looks for override directives for all sub-directories accessed via that VirtualHost also.

Comment: AccessFileName is precisely what he needs :)